# How to enforce a probability distribution on intermediate layer features?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-probability

I have a CNN-LSTM architecture. Now, I want to enforce a probability distribution, say, mixture normal distribution, on the features of an intermediate layer. How can I do this in Keras?

I saw MDN implementation for keras (https://github.com/cpmpercussion/keras-mdn-layer). But this requires that it should be used as last layer of the network. Also, I took a look at tensorflow_probability, but I am not sure if I can use a tensorflow_probability layer for this.

```
enc.add(LSTM(units=64,activation='tanh',return_sequences=False))

# probability layer
enc.add(tfpl.MixtureNormal(num_classes,[64]))

enc.add(Dense(units=num_classes,activation='softmax'))
```

When I tried the above code, it gave me an error as follows:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.

  (0) Invalid argument: Number of ways to split should evenly divide the split dimension, but got split_dim 2 (size = 15) and num_split 2
     [[{{node mixture_normal/MixtureSameFamily/independent_normal/IndependentNormal/split}}]]
     [[metrics/categorical_accuracy/Identity/_251]]

  (1) Invalid argument: Number of ways to split should evenly divide the split dimension, but got split_dim 2 (size = 15) and num_split 2
     [[{{node mixture_normal/MixtureSameFamily/independent_normal/IndependentNormal/split}}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using [`KLDivergenceRegularizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/layers/KLDivergenceRegularizer) with `use_exact=False`, if you don't need to strictly enforce distribution but rather penalize divergence.

Note that most Keras layers accept an `activity_regularizer` arg, e.g.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this out. I saw a class called KLDivergenceAddLoss. It is a layer, while KLDivergenceRegularizer is an activity regularizer that can be applied to a layer. What is the difference? Can I use any of them for my problem?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. However, I am getting an error, which is detailed here. https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/561